# Aggregation Binding templateShareable Error

Tags: sapui5

I am getting the following error when I use a PlanningCalendar Control in my SAPUI5 application. It is not an element that I am destroying or recreating, but instead just used to display data. As a result I think I do not need to concern myself with this error. Is there any way I can get rid of it though? And why exactly is it popping up with the planning calendar? I am using SAPUI5 1.38.9.

> During a clone operation, a template was found that neither was marked
>   with 'templateShareable:true' nor 'templateShareable:false'. The
>   framework won't destroy the template. This could cause errors (e.g.
>   duplicate IDs) or memory leaks (The template is used in aggregation
>   'appointments' of object '__row0').For more information, see
>   documentation under 'Aggregation Binding'. -
>
> ```
>  <PlanningCalendar
>           startDate="{path: '/startDate'}"
>           viewKey="D"
>           rows="{path: '/rows'}">
>           <views>
>               <PlanningCalendarView
>                   key="A"
>                   intervalType="Day"
>                   description="days view"
>                   intervalsS="1"
>                   intervalsM="3"
>                   intervalsL="7"
>                   showSubIntervals="false">
>               </PlanningCalendarView>
>               <PlanningCalendarView
>                   key="D"
>                   intervalType="Hour"
>                   description="hours view"
>                   intervalsS="4"
>                   intervalsM="6"
>                   intervalsL="8"
>                   showSubIntervals="true">
>               </PlanningCalendarView>
>           </views>
>
>           <rows>
>               <PlanningCalendarRow
>                   text="{role}"
>                   nonWorkingDays="{freeDays}"
>                   nonWorkingHours= "{freeHours}"
>                   appointments="{appointments}"
>                   intervalHeaders="{headers}">
>                   <appointments>
>                       <unified:CalendarAppointment
>                           tooltip="{title} {info}"
>                           startDate="{start}"
>                           endDate="{end}"
>                           icon="{pic}"
>                           title="{title}"
>                           text="{info}"
>                           type="{type}">
>                       </unified:CalendarAppointment>
>                   </appointments>
>                   <intervalHeaders>
>                       <unified:CalendarAppointment
>                           startDate="{start}"
>                           endDate="{end}"
>                           icon="{pic}"
>                           title="{title}"
>                           type="{type}">
>                       </unified:CalendarAppointment>
>                   </intervalHeaders>
>               </PlanningCalendarRow>
>           </rows>             
>     </PlanningCalendar>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `templateSharable: false` to your aggregation bindings of `PlanningCalendarRow`.

```
... 
appointments="{path: 'appointments', templateShareable: false}"
intervalHeaders="{path: 'headers', templateShareable: false}"
...
```

This will allow us to let UI5 handle destroying templates when the binding is removed.
You can find the documentation about this [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3a4a9e562988456c9be0ef883ae7da50.html).